# auto remove value or string from list if it start with

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i remove the similar value from list if it start with and keep

one of the value  if it has alot of

for example this is my code

```
list_ph = ['8002378990','8001378990','8202378990','8002378920','8002375990','8002378990','8001378890','8202398990']
```

so this value sould return 3 value when it will remove the value

```
if i[:5]
```

so the result of it will be something like this

```
['8002378990','8001378990','8202378990']
```

without i give it specific value or any thing just sub `value[:5]`

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to remove all duplicates?

Comment: not exactly to remove the duplication to remove value strat with [:5] the first 5 value if it the same to remove other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this problem.

I would first create two empty lists, one for comparing the first five digits, and the other to save your result, say

```
first_five = []
res = []
```

Now, I would loop through all the entries in your `list_ph` and add the number to `res` if the first five digits are not already stored in `first_five`

i.e.

```
for ph in list_ph:
   if ph[:5] not in first_five:
      first_five.append(ph[:5])
      res.append(ph)
```

All of your target numbers should be stored in `res`